# Is this an inductive definition?

Tags: logic, induction

I've been trying to understand what truly is an inductive definition and I came across this one I just 
can't figure out:

$(1)$ $ 0 \in A$

$(2)$ $ n \in A \implies n \in  A$

Comment: I guess the second property isn’t right. Please check that.

Comment: did you mean $\implies n\color{red}{+1}\in A$ ?

Comment: I didn't, no, it's as it's written

Comment: @MatíasSanturio Sounds like a typo.

Comment: I should point out that my main question is whether or not the (2) rule is actually an inductive rule. If $ n \in A \implies n+1 \in  A$ is an inductive rule then why would n+0 not be?

Comment: Are you sure it isn't something like $n\in A\implies n'\in A$ (or some other diacritical symbol on the right side)?

Comment: This does not provide an "inductive definition" because it only tells you $0\in A$; the second rule does not allow you to go beyond $0$. As the second item, as written, is a tautology, these two statements are logically equivalent to just the first. So all they say, put together, is "$0$ is in $A$". This does not tell you anything about who *else* might be in $A$, nor does it tell you anything about whether any other nonnegative integers are or are not in $A$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it's written, (2) is a tautology. The only element $A$ needs to have to satisfy the given conditions is $0$. So we can't use induction to prove anything else.